# Android. Enabling the user to move widgets within a layout

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like the user to be able move a widget within a layout window (in sense drag and drop within the same window).

Is there a good way to do this in simple fashion. I've seen drag and drop examples which are around 1000 lines of code which enable dragging between screens and different widgets but i intend to only move the widget in the screen.

i'm using API level 4 so i cannot use http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html.

Comment: have you tried example from this documentation? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: Yes but i found it a bit unclear.

Comment: well, if you get some results that you are able to test, then just play with it, changing some values and everything will become clear after a while. But it is also very important that you read the process and an "algorithm"(procedures) of drag and drop

Comment: The drag and drop android provides in the documentation referred to in the first comment requires API lvl 11 but i'm using api level 4

Comment: int that case 1000 lines it is :)

Comment: Unfortunately the 1000 line code is API level 8 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure if it is a nice solution, but it works, maybe you should check for some leakages.

```
public class DraGnDroPActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private TextView ll1;
    private FrameLayout layout;

    private float xAxis = 0;
    private float yAxis = 0;

    private TextView newLinearLayout;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.field);

        ll1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        newLinearLayout = ll1;

        ll1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public void redraw() {
        layout.removeAllViews();

        newLinearLayout.setPadding((int) xAxis, (int) yAxis, 0, 0);

        layout.addView(newLinearLayout);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            xAxis = event.getX();
            yAxis = event.getY();
            redraw();

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            System.out.println("intermediate finished");

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Testing" />
```

Comment: Instead of TextView just use LinearLayout, gives same effect